# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/max_gmail_com/yourubl/pyenv'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm really new to Ubuntu/linux, and I'm trying to set up a virtualenv within a folder called yourubl

However causing the following error:

```
max_gmail_com@instance-1:~/yourubl$ virtualenv pyenv

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/max_gmail_com/yourubl/pyenv'
```

I've tried the following:

```
max_gmail_com@instance-1:~$ chmod 775 yourubl
@instance-1:~/yourubl$ chmod 775 /home/maxdenhoed_gmail_com/yourubl
```

What to do?

Please help

Comment: Have you tried using sudo before the command? Sudo lets you run any command as superuser

Comment: Yes I have tried however virtualenv doesn't support sudo unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Look, you need to login with root
Or
Change file ownership using chown USER: GROUP FILE NAME